# App Fabric:Could not set permission on configuration store

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

I am configuring App Fabric on Windows Server 2012 Rc2 but I am facing this error.

Hosting Service:

[image]

Cache Service:
[image]

Cache Node:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer of my question here.We have to just download and copy servermanager.exe in system32 folder because this is not present in WindowsServer2012Rc2 and Share Point 2013 require this during installation.

[enter link description here](http://www.someshinyobject.com/posts/server-2012-r2-and-sharepoint-2013-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web)